# Is it possible to specify that a CSS class have the same width across all members, but stretch-to-fit?

Tags: html, css

Lets say I have multiple elements (div or span) that are either `display: block` or `display: inline-block`.  I want them to all be the same size, but stretched to fit the content of the largest.  I know this can be accomplished with JavaScript, but are there pure HTML/CSS options available?

Example:

```
-----------------------
| Content A           |
-----------------------

-----------------------
| Content B Is Longer |
-----------------------
```

But, if Content B were even longer, they would look like:

```
----------------------------------------
| Content A Is Now Even Longer Than B  |
----------------------------------------

----------------------------------------
| Content B Is Shorter                 |
----------------------------------------
```

Comment: you can place them inside a common parent node and assign float:left to the parent
then give 100% width to the content divs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work if you give them `width: 100%;` and wrap them in a container with `display: inline-block;`. Example: http://jsbin.com/ocifar/1/edit